# Update banco de dados modal

Tags: php, javascript, html, mysql

Fiz um código que atualiza os dados digitados pelo usuário no banco de dados, porém, ele está dando a mensagem de que os dados foram atualizados, mas não atualiza nada. O sistema funciona como uma busca. O usuário digita o número (número e a chave primária) e em seguida abre um *modal* que contém os dados desse número. Ao clicar no *button* "editar", o usuário tem a opção de editar o "funcionário", "rca" e "região", e logo depois salvar. Quando clicar em "salvar" eu preciso que ele faça uma atualização no banco de dados.

Segue o código em que se edita os *inputs*:

```
<?php
include_once("../conn/conexao.php");//faz a conexao com o banco de dados

if(!empty($_POST['numerodigitado'])){

    $numerodigitado = $_POST['numerodigitado'];

    $result = "SELECT * FROM tb_numeros WHERE numero = '$numerodigitado' ";
    $resultado = mysqli_query($conexao, $result);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado);

    if($resultado -> num_rows > 0){
        echo"
        <div class='modal fade' id='squarespaceModa2' tabindex='-1' role='dialog' aria-labelledby='modalLabel' aria-hidden='true'>
            <div class='modal-dialog'>
            <div class='modal-content'>
                <div class='modal-header'>
                    <button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='modal'><span aria-hidden='true'>×</span><span class='sr-only'>Close</span></button>

                <div class='modal-body'>
                <form method='post' action='atualizar.php'>
                    <div class='form-group'>
                        <div class='col-xs-12'><center>
                        <label for='exampleInputPassword1'>Funcionário</label></center>
                        <input type='text' name='funcionario' class='form-control' id='exampleInputPassword1' value=".$row['funcionario']." style='text-align: center;' readonly='readonly' >
                        <br></div>
                    </div>

                    <div class='form-group'>
                        <div class='col-xs-4'><center>
                        <label for='exampleInputPassword1'>Número</label></center>
                        <input type='text' name='numero' class='form-control' id='exampleInputPassword1' value=".$row['numero']." style='text-align: center;' readonly='readonly' >
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class='form-group'>
                        <div class='col-xs-2'><center>
                        <label for='exampleInputPassword1'>RCA</label></center>
                        <input type='text' name='rca' class='form-control' id='exampleInputPassword1' value=".$row['rca']." style='text-align: center;' readonly='readonly' >
                        </div>
                    </div>

                   <div class='form-group'>
                        <div class='col-xs-6'><center>
                        <label for='exampleInputPassword1'>Região</label></center>
                        <input type='text' name='regiao' class='form-control' id='exampleInputPassword1' value=".$row['regiao']." style='text-align: center;' readonly='readonly' >
                        <br></div>
                    </div>

                    <div class='form-group'>
                        <div class='col-xs-6'><center>
                        <label for='exampleInputPassword1'>Número Chip</label></center>
                        <input type='text' name='nchip' class='form-control' id='exampleInputPassword1' value=".$row['nchip']." style='text-align: center;' readonly='readonly' >
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class='form-group'>
                        <div class='col-xs-6'><center>
                        <label for='exampleInputPassword1'>IMEI</label></center>
                        <input type='text' name='imei' class='form-control' id='exampleInputPassword1' value=".$row['imei']." style='text-align: center;' readonly='readonly' >
                        <br></div>
                    </div>

                    <div class='form-group'>
                        <div class='col-xs-12'><center>
                        <label for='exampleInputPassword1'>Cadastrado Por</label></center>
                        <input type='text' name='usuario' class='form-control' id='exampleInputPassword1' value=".$row['usuario']." style='text-align: center;' readonly='readonly' >
                        <br></div>
                    </div>

                    <div class='form-group'>
                        <div class='col-xs-6'><center>
                        <button type='button' class='btn btn-default btn-lg btn-block' role='button' id='btnEditar' ><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-pencil'></span>&nbsp;Editar</button>
                        </center></div>
                    </div>

                    <div class='form-group'>
                        <div class='col-xs-6'><center>
                        <button class='btn btn-default btn-lg btn-block' role='button' type='submit' value='Cadastrar' name='Salvar'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-ok'></span>&nbsp;Salvar</button>
                        </center></div>
                    </div>
                </form>
                </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){ $('#squarespaceModa2').modal(); });  
        </script>";

    } 
    else {
       echo "<script>
            alert('Número não encontrado.');
            window.location='index.php';
        </script>"; 
    }
}
```

Agora o código do `atualizar.php`:

```
<?php
session_start();
include("../conn/conexao.php");

    $numero = $_GET['numero'];

    $funcionario= $_POST['funcionario'];
    $rca= $_POST['rca'];
    $regiao= $_POST['regiao'];
    $nome=$_SESSION['nome'];

    $up = mysqli_query($conexao, "UPDATE tb_numeros SET funcionario='$funcionario', rca='$rca', regiao='$regiao', usuario='$nome'  WHERE numero = '$numero' ")or die (mysqli_error($conexao));

    if($up):
        echo "<script>
                alert('Alterado com sucesso.');
                window.location='index.php';
            </script>"; 
    else:
        echo "<script>
                alert('Ocorreu um erro ao atualizar, entre em contato com o administrador.');
                window.location='index.php';
            </script>";
    endif;
```

**Observação**: tenho um *script* que faz com que os libere os *inputs*:

```
<script language='JavaScript'>
 $("#btnEditar").on('click', function() {
  $('input[name="funcionario"]').removeAttr('readonly');
  $('input[name="rca"]').removeAttr('readonly');
  $('input[name="regiao"]').removeAttr('readonly');
});
</script>
```

Comment: Como se consegue editar campos com atributo `readonly='readonly'`?

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo então esqueci de informa eu tenho um script que ao clicar no botão editar os inputs são liberados: <script language='JavaScript'>
 $("#btnEditar").on('click', function() {
  $('input[name="funcionario"]').removeAttr('readonly');
  $('input[name="rca"]').removeAttr('readonly');
  $('input[name="regiao"]').removeAttr('readonly');
});
</script>

Comment: Agora sim, entendido!

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo editei lá na pergunta também

Comment: Ótimo, e como você está passando as variáveis para a atualizar.php?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Uma solução** - alterar a sua tag `form` acrescentando no `action` o parâmetro `numero=$numerodigitado` para que o arquivo `atualizar.php` possa criar a variável `$numero = $_GET['numero'];` necessária para executar a clausula `WHERE numero = '$numero'` da declaração `UPDATE`

```
<form action='atualizar.php?numero=$numerodigitado' method='POST'>
```

**Outra solução** - no arquivo `atualizar.php` alterar `$numero = $_GET['numero'];`  para `$numero = $_POST['numero'];` já que o mesmo é enviado via post pelo formulario, tornado-se assim desnecessário recuperá-lo via GET.

**Uma observação** - caso não exista uma `$_SESSION['nome'];` definida em algum instante na sua aplicação, faz-se necessário alterar no arquivo `atualizar.php`

```
$nome=$_SESSION['nome'];  para `$nome=$_POST['usuario'];`
```

Answer (score 0):

Seu formulário usa o método post para envio de dados, então altere o arquivo atualizar.php

```
$numero = $_GET['numero']; //altera aqui para $_POST['numero']
$funcionario= $_POST['funcionario'];
$rca= $_POST['rca'];
$regiao= $_POST['regiao'];
$nome=$_SESSION['nome'];  //altera aqui para $_POST['usuario']
```